# COMO RETORNAR UMA RESPOSTA PARA UMA PERGUNTA COM JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Comecei agora em JavaScript e estou tentando retornar algumas respostas de perguntas usando JavaScript, mas não estou conseguindo, não sei aonde estou errando.

```js
function conferir() {
  var A = document.getElementsById('question')
  var B = document.getElementsById('first')
  var C = document.getElementsById('second')

  if (A == B) {
    greeting = 'Você é muito fã';
  } else {
    greeting = 'Talvez curta um Dolly';
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Quiz </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/style.css">
  <script src="Style/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 id="question"> Você é fã de Coca-Cola? </h3>
  <input type="radio" id="first">
  <label> SIM </label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="second">
  <label> NÃO </label><br>

  <br>

  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = conferir()">
        Resultado</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução do seu problema é esse aqui:

1. Remova o trecho de código do botão: Resultado e deixe apenas a chamada da função no seu código:

`<button type="button" onclick="conferir()">Resultado</button>`

1. Atente-se a escrita da sintaxe na sua pergunta o existe um comando errado. Não é
   `getElementsById` e sim `getElementById` no **singular**.
2. Você na estava declarando e nem retornando valor da variavél `gretting`.

```
function conferir() { 

    var A = document.getElementById('question');
    var B = document.getElementById('first') 
    var C = document.getElementById('second');
    var greeting = "";

    if (A == B) { 
        greeting = 'Você é muito fã'; 
    } else { 
        greeting = 'Talvez curta um Dolly'; 
    }

    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = greeting;   
}
```

Apenas substitua os trechos apontados e teste para ver se funcionou.

Segue o exemplo funcionando:

```js
function conferir() {

  var A = document.getElementById('question');
  var B = document.getElementById('first')
  var C = document.getElementById('second');
  var greeting = "";

  if (A == B) {
    greeting = 'Você é muito fã';
  } else {
    greeting = 'Talvez curta um Dolly';
  }

  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = greeting;

}
```

```html
<h3 id="question"> Você é fã de Coca-Cola? </h3>
<input type="radio" id="first">
<label> SIM </label><br>
<input type="radio" id="second">
<label> NÃO </label><br>

<br>

<button type="button" onclick="conferir()">Resultado</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui entender, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Haviam alguns erros no codigo.

- O seu codigo esta permitindo selecionar as 2 respostas.
  Para corrigir os 2 inputs devem ter o mesmo name.
  Isso fara com que apenas 1 possa ser selecionado.
  Assim:

  ```
    <input type="radio" id="first" name="anser">
    <label for="first">SIM </label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="second" name="anser">
    <label for="second">NÃO </label><br>
  ```

  Perceba também que adicionei um atributo for, no label, que linka ele ao ID do input
- A verificação esta incorreta
  A == B, sempre retornara false pois são coisas diferentes
  A é um input e B é outro.
  Você deve verificar se A está marcado ou B esta marcado, quando clicar
  no Botão

  ```
    const A = document.getElementById('first') 
    const B = document.getElementById('second')

    if (A.checked) { 
      alert('Você é muito fã de Coca-Cola'); 
    } else if (B.checked) { 
      alert('Talvez curta um Dolly'); 
    }
  ```
- Não use VAR! veja videos sobre let e const, são mais recomendados hoje em dia.
- Como ja citado o correto é getElementById, no singular pois vc ta pegando apenas uma "coisa";
- O evento onclick deve referenciar apenas a função conferir

  ```
  <button type="button" onclick="conferir()">
    Resultado
  </button>
  ```

**Codigo completo abaixo**

```
  <h3> Você é fã de Coca-Cola? </h3>
  <input type="radio" id="first" name="anser">
  <label for="first">SIM </label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="second" name="anser">
  <label for="second">NÃO </label><br>
  
  <br>

  <button type="button" onclick="conferir()">
    Resultado
  </button>
  
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>

    function conferir() { 
      const A = document.getElementById('first') 
      const B = document.getElementById('second')

      if (A.checked) { 
        alert('Você é muito fã de Coca-Cola'); 
      } else if (B.checked) { 
        alert('Talvez curta um Dolly'); 
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui entender, me ajudou muito, vou usar como base para entender melhor outros projetos também, mais uma vez muito obrigado!